# ES6 export default AssignmentExpression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

```
export default var foo = {...}
```

It's AssignmentExpression and valid es6 syntax? JSHint says it Expected an identifier and instead saw 'var'.

On last spec I not found any relation with VariableStatement and AssignmentExpression.

Comment: Are you sure you want `var` in there? It seems like you should just have `export default foo` **or** `export var foo`. I can't find any examples where they use `export default var ...`

Comment: The modules spec recently underwent big changes. I'd avoid ES6 modules in favor of something like requirejs if I were you.(at least for now)

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = {...}
```

is **not** an `AssignmentExpression`. `AssignmentExpression` is almost the top level non-terminal symbol that represents [*all* expression](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-expressions), i.e. basically every expression is an `AssignmentExpression`.

`var` only appears in a variable declaration or a `for` loop, so drop the `var`.