# cannot export const arrow function

Tags: ecmascript-6

new to ES6, I was trying to make a React simple functional component like this

```
// ./Todo.jsx

    export default const Todo = ({
      todos,
      onTodoClick,
    }) => (
      <ul>
        {todos.map( (todo, i) =>
          <li key     = {i} 
              onClick = {() => onTodoClick(i) } 
              style   = {{textDecoration: todo.completed ? 'line-through': 'none' }}
              >
            {todo.text}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
```

But

```
// Another file 
import Todo from './Todos.jsx';
console.log(Todo) // undefined
```

did not yield the arrow function.

but if I leave off the "const todo =" part in the export link, like so

```
    export default ({
      todos,
      onTodoClick,
    }) => (...)
```

It gets successfully imported.

Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 export default AssignmentExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925628/es6-export-default-assignmentexpression)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You're trying to export a default and declare a variable at the same time, which is invalid syntax.

Consider the following, since we know that you can declare multiple variables using only one instance of the keyword, `var a, b, c;` the export definition wouldn't make sense at all.

```
export default var a, b, c;
```

What would that mean? What would get exported?

Furthermore, using the `export default` syntax already creates a variable called `default` that needs to contain a value or reference.

Export the variable instead if you want to make it a constant.

```
const Todo = () => {};

export default Todo;
```

There is a [thread about this on ESDiscuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/why-is-export-default-var-a-1-invalid-syntax)

Comment: I see, but export class Todo extends Component {...} is not considered as declaration of a variable but a class which is valid, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but using the `class` keyword is only syntactic sugar AND you cannot declare more than 1 class in the same go anyways. `class A, B, C` is in valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks a million, it makes a lot of sense, the part about you can var/const multiple things and export wouldn't know which to act on.

Comment: The spec also has [a useful table](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-42) on the different types of allowed `export`

Answer (score 10):

**Arrow function default export:**

```
import React from 'react';
const Body=()=>(
    <div>This is my body</div>
);
export default Body;
```

**Arrow function Named exports:**

1. First Way

> ```
> import React from 'react';
>
> export const Body = () => (
>     <div>This is my body</div>
> );
> ```

2. Second Way

> ```
> import React from 'react';
>
> const Body = () => {
>     return <div>This is my body</div>
> };
>
> export {Body};
> ```

You can also use 1 default and multiple named exports in the same file check below examples:

**Example 1:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Body1 = () => {
    return <div>This is my body1</div>
};

const Body2 = () => {
    return <div>This is my body2</div>
};

export {Body1, Body2};
```

> ```
> you can import by using below code.
> import {Body1, Body2} from 'bodyComponentPath';
> ```

**Example 2**

```
import React from 'react';
const MainBody = () => {
    return <div>This is my MainBody</div>
};

const Body1 = () => {
    return <div>This is my body1</div>
};

const Body2 = () => {
    return <div>This is my body2</div>
};

export {Body1, Body2};
export default MainBody;
```

> ```
> you can import by using below code.
> import MainBody, {Body1, Body2} from 'bodyComponentPath';
> ```

/* use named export components inside the curly bracket only */

> import MainBody, {Body1, Body2} from 'bodyComponentPath';